# Creating a message box, if Dropdown answer is yes. VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a working dropdown box that gives the answers yes & no.  When "yes" is selected I need to create a message box that displays a simple message and allows the user to click ok, to get back to the survey.

I have been working with it, and tried several things but no luck.  What would the code look like, and where exactly would I place it to fire at the right time.  I am working in VB, with an aspx & aspx.vb page.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that message boxes on the web are a client technology, so you'll have to do this via javascript, using the `alert()` function.

Comment: ok, but how do I get it to trigger when the user chooses "yes" in the drop down?  Also, this is an aspx page, what will the code look like to implement javascript?

Comment: mdmullinax has probably the most straightforward answer to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes most straight forward but inline javascript, just like inline CSS, should be avoided. Check out this link for reasons why. http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: @anothershrubery: You're right - personally, I'd hook up the change event to the function in the document.ready, using jQuery, like `$("#<%: ddlQuestion.ClientID %>").change(questionChanged);`, then a function like: `function questionChanged() { if ($(this).val() == "yes") { alert("Some Message"); } }`.  But the idea is pretty much the same.

Comment: Why use jQuery, a javascript library, when you can do it in javascript in a couple of lines? jQuery is great for a lot of things but would be complete overkill for something of this nature.

Comment: With jQuery, you get browser compatibility, so you don't have to worry about how your browser executes the XMLHttpRequest - AJAX is actually built-in. You can also hook up to the JSON library easily to receive .NET objects as javascript objects without any extra work. Plus it's just cached once in the browser, so it's not like it's an ongoing performance difference. Once I started using jQuery for day-to-day javascript tasks, I've never turned back.

Answer (score 1):

one sort of classic way to do this is add the `onchange` attribute to the `DropDownList`

```
Dim message As String = "Custom Message"
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if (this.value === 'yes') alert('" + message + "');")
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should help you get something similar for your page.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">  

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowAlert()
        {
            var dropDownList = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
            var dropDownListValue = dropDownList.value;
            if (dropDownListValue == "1")
            {
                alert('This is your message box!');
            }
        };
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="ShowAlert();">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>    
</body>
```